# Ubuntu Desktop with GUI and SSH access

Tags: 12.10, server, ssh, gui

I used to have Ubuntu Server 12.10, and I used to connect to it with my Windows PC using SSH. All I had to do was turn my server computer on and next thing I could do was run my PuTTY and connect to it. Lately I've been needing GUI, so I went and installed GUI to server, but got everything messed up so I did fresh install of Ubuntu Desktop 12.10.

Now I want to be able to use this new configuration similar way to my old one. I want to turn my server pc (only tower) on and then immediately be able log in to it, either by using PuTTY or connection to remote desktop. But I have run into few problems.

Problem is that I cant connect to it before I have signed in locally on server PC.

is there any work around for this?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you encrypted your home folder. Authentication with ssh is not enough to decrypt your home folder (the .ssh is encrypted with your home folder). You must authenticate at console to decrypt the folder first. Alternatives are to decrypt your home folder, or to change sshd_config such that it does not need to read from your encrypted home folder.

Comment: how safe it is to decrypt my home folder? and also how safe is to disable login on startup?

Comment: sounds like a judgement call. I cannot decide what is safe to you.